# How to ignore #cdata-section of HTML content during XML to JSON conversion in C#

Tags: c#, json, xml

I am trying to convert below xml containing html code to json using Newtonsoft json in c sharp,

```
  <Content>
   <richtext> <![CDATA[<p> <strong>This is sample richtext content </strong> </p> ]]</richtext>
   <htmlcontent><![CDATA[ <p> <strong>This is html content </strong> ]]</p> </htmlcontent>
   <others> sample </others>
  </Content>
```

My C# code is

```
string xmlContent = @"<Content><richtext><![CDATA[ <p> <strong>This is sample richtext content </strong> </p> ]]></richtext><htmlcontent> <![CDATA[<p> <strong>This is html content </strong> </p> ]]></htmlcontent><others> sample </others></Content>";
doc.LoadXml(xmlContent);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine("JSON is :" + jsonText);
```

My output is

```
    {
  "Content": {
    "richtext": {
      "#cdata-section": " <p> <strong>This is sample richtext content </strong> </p> "
    },
    "htmlcontent": {
      "#cdata-section": "<p> <strong>This is html content </strong> </p> "
    },
    "others": " sample "
  }
}
```

My expected output is

```
{
  "Content": {
    "richtext": "<p> <strong>This is sample richtext content </strong> </p>",
    "htmlcontent": "<p> <strong>This is html content </strong> </p>",
    "others": " sample "
  }
}
```

Is there any way to remove the  #cdata-section element in XML during JSON conversion.

Comment: Your XML is invalid. In that XML `<p>` isn't HTML it's an xml node `p`. If you want to embed HTML into XML you need to use CData

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I store html page in a xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978316/how-do-i-store-html-page-in-a-xml-file)

Comment: Thanks Liam, i verified adding the HTML content in CDATA, still i get "#cdata-section" node which is not required in output. Can you tell how to remove this in the output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove CDATA nodes from document. Paste the HTML as the raw data - it will be inserted with escaping the tags.

Let's use Linq2Xml instead of `XmlDocument`. It more convenient.

```
string xmlContent = @"<Content><richtext><![CDATA[ <p> <strong>This is sample richtext content </strong> </p> ]]></richtext><htmlcontent> <![CDATA[<p> <strong>This is html content </strong> </p> ]]></htmlcontent><others> sample </others></Content>";
var doc = XElement.Parse(xmlContent);

var cdata = doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XCData>().ToList();
foreach(var cd in cdata)
{
    cd.Parent.Add(cd.Value);
    cd.Remove();
}

Console.WriteLine(doc);

string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(jsonText);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Alexander Petrov & Liam for your responses, it helped me.

Comment: one small issue that i am facing after serilazation , it introduces \n characters in the output if my cdata contains content in different lines.can you tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @user3113876 - Don't ask in comments. Edit your question or ask new one. Show us sample content with different lines.