# Import HTML table to SQL server

Tags: javascript, html, sql, sql-server

I need to import a dynamic created HTML table to SQL server (using Visual Studio, C#). How can I do it? Maybe do you have articles/books? And the second problem is: will SQL database change when HTML table changes?

Comment: Where do you have that HTML table ? and did you write some code in C# to do that?

Answer (score 0):

HTML table is nothing but a string. You can store it like any other string data. Better use `NVARCHAR` as data type.

If your HTML is well formed you can even store it as XML in the database. Check this for more detail [HTML as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978316/how-do-i-store-html-page-in-a-xml-file)

You need to read the InnerHTML of the table using JavaScript . Post it to the server. Make sure that you encode the HTML before storing it.

Regarding any change in HTML table, you need to update it back to the DB.